# Can we access the compiler path from within a source file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, preprocessor

I am looking for a way of programatically accessing the *path* of the compiler that is compiling the current source file (I'd assume something like a macro here, think of `__FILE__` and friends).
Ideally something compiler-independent, but I also don't mind a compiler-specific extension (in that case preferably gcc), if only that is possible.

Specifically looking at gcc, I looked up the [predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html) but couldn't find anything.
What I am looking for would be something like this:

```
printf("The compiler that compiled this file is located at %s\n", __COMPILERPATH__);
//  -> "The compiler that compiled this file is located at /usr/bin/gcc"
```

But there is no such thing as `__COMPILERPATH__`.

Comment: may I ask why you want a *path*?

Comment: Sounds like a [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What you seem to *really* want is to determine what compiler compiled the code. But what you are *asking* is how to determine paths to the compiler. A compiler is not uniquely determined by where it is located in the filesystem. I can create a symlink for cl.exe that is called gcc. Also, the compiler could be installed at any arbitrary location, so knowing the path doesn't help you. Ask the question you *really* want an answer to.

Comment: i doubt that compilers offer such macro, but you can define it yourself, eg with gcc`-DCOMPILERPATH=/path/to/compiler/`

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Unfortunately that's a wrong guess. If I were to ask what compiler compiled the code, I would just query the respective predefined macros (`_MSC_VER`, for example). In the ecosystem that I am working in, I need to print out the path to the compiler binary that was used to compile a specific file. I was just curious to see if there is a predefined constant for that matter or whether I need to inject a definition as suggested by the answers below. After all, macros like `__FILE__` exist, so this made me wonder if there is anything similar for querying the compiler path.

Comment: I would name it `CC_PATH` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way in C++.

A simple approach is to pass the pass to the compiler path as a macro definition upon compilation. The syntax for that is compiler specific, but a build system generator can help with that.

If std::embed [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1040r0.html) was accepted into a future standard, then following trick could work: `std::embed("/proc/self/cmdline")`. However, this is Linux specific.

Comment: Passing the compiler path as macro definition wasn't exactly what I was looking for (although it works of course), but at first sight I really like the idea of `std::embed`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're compiling a C program with gcc, you could do the following:

```
gcc -DCOMPILER_PATH="$(gcc --print-prog-name=cc1)" ...
```

eg:

#### file: idgcc.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)

int main(void) {
  printf("Compiled with gcc v%d.%d.%d at %s\n",
         __GNUC__,
         __GNUC_MINOR__,
         __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__,
         STRINGIFY(COMPILER_PATH));
}
```

#### Build and run

```sh
$ gcc-10 -DCOMPILER_PATH="$(gcc --print-prog-name=cc1)" idgcc.c && ./a.out
Compiled with gcc v10.1.0 at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-1-gnu/7/cc1
```

Comment: This is what I would do. It's an irritation to have to type the stuff at a prompt, but it's fine in a Makefile.

Comment: @KevinBoone: any C project large enough to need a hack like this has a makefile or equivalent :-)